# Internal working of byte streams. Difference between write(65) and write('A')?

Tags: java, java-io, file-writing, bytestream

Both of these lines will write me **letter A** in a `file`. Can someone tell me how are they different in internal working?

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("test.txt");
fileOutputStream.write(65);
fileOutputStream.write('A');
```

[EDIT]: I am more interested in how converting works in both of these cases. As I know what ASCII and UNICODE tables are.

Comment: Well they both call `write(int)`, so are you unclear how `'A'` is cast to `int`?

Comment: @Kayaman yes :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's start with the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileOutputStream.html) for `FileOutputStream`.  If you look at it you will see that there are three `write` methods:

> - `void write​(byte[] b)` - Writes `b.length` bytes from the specified byte array to this file output stream.
> - `void write​(byte[] b, int off, int len)` - Writes `len` bytes from the specified byte array starting at offset `off` to this file output
>   stream.
> - `void write​(int b)` - Writes the specified byte to this file output stream.

So what does it tell us?

1. Clearly, when we call `fileOutputStream.write(65)` or `fileOutputStream.write('A')`, we are NOT calling the first or second overloads of the `write` method.  We are actually calling the third one.
2. Therefore when we call `fileOutputStream.write('A')`, the `char` value `'A'` is converted to an `int` value.  This conversion is a *primitive widening conversion* from `char` to `int`.  It is equivalent to doing an explicit type cast; i.e `(int) 'A'`.
3. Primitive widening casts from an integer type (e.g. `char`) to a larger integer type (e.g. `int`) is simply a matter of making it bigger.  In this case we just add 16 zero bits on the front.  (Because `char` is unsigned and `int` is signed.)
4. When we look at the ASCII and Unicode code tables we see that they both use the same value for the letter capital A.  It is 65 in decimal or 41 in hexadecimal.  In other words `(int) 'A'` and `65` are the same value.
5. So when you take the implicit widening conversion that happens,  `fileOutputStream.write('A')` and `fileOutputStream.write(65)` are actually calling `write` *with the same parameter value*.
6. Finally, the javadoc for `write(int)` refers to [this javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/OutputStream.html#write(int)) which says:

   > Writes the specified byte to this output stream. The general contract for write is that one byte is written to the output stream. *The byte to be written is the eight low-order bits of the argument b.* The 24 high-order bits of b are ignored.

   That explains how the `int` magically turns into a `byte`.

---

Note that this only prints something sensible because we picked a character in the ASCII character set.  It so happens that Unicode chose to mirror the ASCII character set as the first 128 Unicode codepoints.

If you replaced `A` with some character outside of the ASCII charset, there is a good chance that `OutputStream::write(int)` would garble it.

It is better to use a `FileWriter` rather than a `FileOutputStream` when outputting text.